# Proving that a set of vectors isn't a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have the set $A = \{(x,y,z) | x\cdot y \cdot z=0\}$ and I wanna prove that this is not a valid subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$ so I tried to prove that it's not closed under addition by taking a vector $u = \begin{bmatrix} a{_1} \cr b{_1}\cr c{_1}\end{bmatrix}$ and $v = \begin{bmatrix} a{_2} \cr b{_2}\cr c{_2}\end{bmatrix}$ then $u+v$ is equal to $\begin{bmatrix} a{_1}+a{_2} \cr b{_1}+b{_2}\cr c{_1}+c{_2}\end{bmatrix}$  and if $u+v$ is in $A$ then  $(a{_1}+a{_2})\cdot(b{_1}+b{_2})\cdot(c{_1}+c{_2})=0  $ has to be true. And this can only be true if $a{_1}=-a{_2}$, $b{_1}=-b{_2}$ or $c{_1}=-c{_2}$ and my question is where exactly do I go from here? Like this still doesn't look like a solid proof to me like what about this really proves what I'm trying to? Like what if $u$ and $v$'s only rows that hold the condition and make the vectors valid elements of $A$ are the exact solutions $a_1=-a_2$, $b_1=-b_2$ or $c_1=-c_2$. I don't even know if that made sense but basically can anyone help me understand how this is a $100\%$ proof that this set isn't closed under addition? Like just tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Just come up with *one* example of two vectors $u,v\in A$ whose sum is not in $A$. For example, if $u=(1,1,0)$ then can you find an appropriate $v\in A$ such that $u+v$ is not in $A$?

Comment: To prove an "equality" involving variables is not true, you have to produce an example where it is failing. And producing examples involves choice of values that you might assign to a variable. So in proving that an equality is not true , if you proceed in a general way , then you leave it upto chance whether it holds true or not. So you **HAVE** to produce a counter example where an equality does not hold and that would "complete" your proof that the equality is not true in general . In short , in order to show something is not true in general, you provide a specific example where it fails.

Answer (score 3):

If
$$
u=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\ \ \ \ \mathrm{and}\ \ \ \ v=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix},
$$
then $u$ and $v$ belong to $A$, but $u+v$ doesn't. So, $A$ is not a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I get these examples with just two simple vectors but what if I wanna prove it algebraically like I did how would you interpret what I showed at the end? (a1+a2)⋅(b1+b2)⋅(c1+c2)=0  has to be true. And this can only be true if a1=−a2, b1=−b2 or c1=−c2 do these solutions PROVE that the set isn't closed under addition? How? I can find two vectors and just prove it like that but if I wanna do it like this how do you interpret these solutions and how do they prove the set is closed under addition?

Comment: What I did *does* prove algebraically that $A$ is not closed under addition. Asserting that $A$ is closed under addition is to assert that, when $u,v\in A$, $u+v\in A$. Therefore, asserting that $A$ is **not** closed under addition is to assert that *there are* two vectors $v,w\in A$ such that $v+w\notin A$. And that is what I have proved.

Comment: Okay but still I'm trying to prove it that in a slightly different way with just two vectors u,v that are just general vectors that belong to A and I'm trying to prove that when you add them both together that vector is not always in A and my final solutions were that u+v is only in A if a1=-a2 or b1=-b2 or c1=-c2 how do these solutions prove it's not closed under addition?

Comment: They prove it if you provide a concrete example, such as $a_1=1$, $a_2=0$, $a_3=0$, $b_1=0$, $b_2=1$, and $b_3=1$. Which, by the way, is what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Since one of x,y,z has to be 0. just jouce  on vector with x,y≠0, z=0 and one x=0, y,z≠0 and add them
one single counterexample proofs that it is not linear.

Comment: I get these examples with just two simple vectors but what if I wanna prove it algebraically like I did how would you interpret what I showed at the end? (a1+a2)⋅(b1+b2)⋅(c1+c2)=0  has to be true. And this can only be true if a1=−a2, b1=−b2 or c1=−c2 do these solutions PROVE that the set isn't closed under addition? How? I can find two vectors and just prove it like that but if I wanna do it like this how do you interpret these solutions and how do they prove the set is closed under addition?

Answer (score 0):

Recall the following result.

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and let $H\subseteq V$. We will say that $H$ is a vector subspace of $V$ if, and only if, the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. $\vec{0}_{V}\in H$,
> 2. $\forall h_{1},h_{2}\in H:\quad h_{1}+h_{2}\in H$.
> 3. $\forall \alpha \in F, \forall h\in H:\quad \alpha \cdot h\in H$.

Now, notice the importance of the *universal quantifiers* "$\forall$" what does it mean "for all". That is to say that if we prove that there are two vectors that do not satisfy this property, that destroys the fact that the quantifier "for all" holds and therefore the total proposition should not hold, from which it should follow that the subset is not a subspace vector of the vector space.

Now,

- The vector space $V=\mathbb{R}^{3}$.
- The set $A=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}:\quad x\cdot y\cdot z=0\}$ is a subset of $V$.

Hence we can use the characterisation given in the first parte here. So we need to see if $1,2$ and $3$ are satisfied

1. $(0,0,0)\in H$ because $0\cdot 0\cdot 0=0$, that is $\vec{0}_{V}\in H$.
2. Let $h_{1}=(a_{1},b_{1},c_{1})\in H$ and $h_{2}=(a_{2},b_{2},c_{2})\in  H$ so by definition of $A$ we have
   $$a_{1}\cdot b_{1}\cdot c_{1}=0,\quad a_{2}\cdot b_{2}\cdot c_{2}=0$$

Now, $h_{1}+h_{2}=(a_{1}+a_{2},b_{1}+b_{2},c_{1}+c_{2})\in H$ **if** $$(a_{1}+a_{2})(b_{1}+b_{2})(c_{1}+c_{2})=0$$
Expanding the RHS, we have

$$\underbrace{a_{1}b_{1}c_{1}}_{=0; \text{by hypothesis}}+\underbrace{a_{2}b_{2}c_{2}}_{=0;\text{by hypothesis}}+\color{red}{\text{other terms}}=0?$$
So we ask ourselves: is the RHS equal to $0$, always regardless of or at the choice of our vectors? I think now you can clearly see that the appearance of those $\color{red}{\text{other terms}}$ can certainly make the RHS not equal to $0$. So *we provide a **counterexample** because **it is the correct way to prove that $A$ is not a vector subspace***.

*Counterexample:*

Let $h_{1}=(1,0,1)\in H$ and $h_{2}=(0,1,1)\in H$ but $$h_{1}+h_{2}=(1+0,0+1,1+1)$$ is not in $H$ because $$(1+0)(0+1)(1+1)=(1\cdot 0\cdot 1)+(0\cdot 1\cdot 1)+\color{red}{2}=2\not=0.$$

Therefore $A$ is not vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: A simple counterexample is also a "algebraic way" of proving or disproving something, so why talke  a general  long way  if a counterexample is so easy?